# Phone NUMBER function

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I'm trying to build a function that checks to see if a phone number is valid.

My requirement are
All digits
Length = 10
First and fourth characters can't be 0 or 1

I hope I'm not reinventing the wheel.

I can't seem to get passed the first test syntax error and was hoping someone can help me out.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_phone_number( p_str IN VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  IF REGEXP_LIKE(p_str, '^[[:digit:]]+$')
THEN
    RETURN 1;
  
  RETURN 0;
END;
```

Comment: You're missing `end if;`. Control statements like `if` and `loop` are always block statements, also if they contain just a single statement.

Comment: What output are you getting? Is there an error? Note that in PL/SQL the `IF` clause should be explicitly closed with `END IF;`

Comment: Honestly you should such a validation logic should not be implemented in database in PL/SQL. Look at the library libphonenumber from Google it offers far better reliability https://github.com/google/libphonenumber. You can use it on client side or as Java stored procedure on DB side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_phone_number( p_str IN VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  IF REGEXP_LIKE(p_str, '^[2-9][0-9]{2}[2-9][0-9]{6}$') THEN
    RETURN 1;
  ELSE  
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

*Note: your code is missing an `END IF;` (and, maybe, an `ELSE`).*